# Issues with php form using Curl

Tags: php, curl

Issues with php form using Curl. The below code works fine as stated

but when i wants to post the address from form fields by adding the followings, not seems to work

```
$data = array(
        'address' => $_POST['address']

);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

can anyone help

Comment: You need to send it as a query (i.e `?address=ADDRESS_HERE&fields..`) - [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 1):

try to send your post data as a query string

```
$str = '';
foreach($data as $key => $val){
  $str.= $key.'='.$val.'&';
}
rtrim($str,'&');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'address='.$_POST['address']);
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

According comment error you need code:-

```
<?php 
$address = "Capitol Avenue, Elsmere, Kentucky"; 
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); 
$address_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $address_url.'?address='.$address); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); 
curl_close($ch); 
$response_a = json_decode($response); ?>
```

Comment: i have tried the above option but not working. here is my entire code

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(0);

 
$address=$_POST['address'];
//$address = "Capitol Avenue, Elsmere, Kentucky";

$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);
 
$address_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $address_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
 
$response_a = json_decode($response);
 

?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/post.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "address=$_POST['address']");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```